# How to test useEffect of nested hook value with Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have two custom hooks:

- `useInTestHook` hook that I testing
- `useNestedHook` that been tested and returns value

`useInTestHook` hook has logic:

```js
export const useInTestHook = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<number>(1);

  const { isActive } = useNestedHook();

  useEffect(() => {
    isActive && value !== 2 && setValue(2);
  }, [isActive]);

  return { value };
}
```

I'm using `nextjs` and `testing-library`. Want to make test for it.

I doing a mock of import:

```
jest.mock("./hooks/useNestedHook", () => ({
  useNestedHook: () => ({
    isActive: false,
  }),
}));
```

And making a spy to set the value:

```
describe("some test", () => {
  let nestedHookValue: NestedHookResult;

  beforeEach(() => {
    nestedHookValue = { isActive: false };
    jest.spyOn(NestedHookModule, "useNestedHook").mockReturnValue(nestedHookValue);
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it("useEffect test", () => {
    const renderedHook = renderHook(() => useInTestHook());
    expect(renderedHook.result.current.value).toEqual(1);
    act(() => {
      nestedHookValue.isActive = true;
    });
    expect(renderedHook.result.current.value).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

As you guessing, the second expect not working. Because hook not been rerendered with value update. How I have to work with it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

1. To force spy work correctly, mock of hook has to be function

```
jest.mock("./hooks/useNestedHook", () => ({
  useNestedHook: jest.fn(),
}));
```

2. To activate `useEffect` of hook, only think what I had to do is call rerender:

```
  it("useEffect test", () => {
    const renderedHook = renderHook(() => useInTestHook());
    expect(renderedHook.result.current.value).toEqual(1);
    nestedHookValue.isActive = true;
    renderedHook.rerender();
    expect(renderedHook.result.current.value).toEqual(2);
  });
```